# Mongodb aggregate distinct with sort and limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection `objects`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55fa65046db58e7d0c8b456a"),
    "object_id" : "1651419",
    "user" : {
        "id" : "65593",
        "cookie" : "9jgkm7ME1HDFD4K6j8WWvg",
    },
    "createddate" : ISODate("2015-09-17T10:00:20.945+03:00")
}
```

Every time user visits object's page it stores as separate record in collection. Now i need to get array of *last N* visited objects. It should be *distinct*, so array should have N unique records. Also, it should be sorted by `createddate`.
So if the user visited `object_id = 1`, then `object_id = 2` two times, after that visited `object_id = 3` and again `object_id = 1` the array should contain:

```
{
    visits : [1, 3, 2]
}
```

(distinct and sorted by time of last visit).

I tried to use construction like

```
db.objects.aggregate([
    {$match: {'user.id' : '65593'}},
    {$sort: { 'createddate':-1 }},
    {$project: {'id': '$user.id', 'obj' : '$object_id'}},
    {$group: {_id:'$id', 'obj': {$addToSet: '$obj'}}},
    {$project:{_id:0, 'obj':'$obj'}}
])
```

but it returns array that not sorted and also i can't limit array size.

Comment: `object_id` should be integer not string.

Comment: @user3100115, no, it shouldn't at all. I have some alphanumberic ID's with no problem.

Comment: I think your first match and sort are the right approach if you want to know the last N visited objects of an user, then you should group by object id and you may want to look at [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) functionality to finish the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution i expected.

```
db.objects.aggregate([
  {$match: {'user.id' : '65593'}},
  {$group : { 
      _id : '$object_id',
      dt : {$max: '$createddate'}
      }
  },
  {$sort: {'dt':-1}},
  {$limit:5},
  {$group : { 
      _id :null,
      'objects' : {$push:'$_id'}
      }
  },
  {$project: {_id:0, 'objects':'$objects'}}
])
```

It returns limited to N distinct array sorted backwards by `createddate`. 
Thank everyone for help!

Answer (score 4):

The [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator and "sets" in general for MongoDB are not ordered in any way. Insead, get the "distinct" values by grouping on them first, then apply to the array after sorting them:

```js
db.objects.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "user.id": "65593" } },
    { "$sort": { "user.id": 1, "createddate": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$user.id", 
            "object_id": "$object_id"
        },
        "createddate": { "$first": "$createddate" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id._id": 1, "createddate": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "obj": { "$push": "$_id.object_id" }        
    }}
])
```

So if you want the discovery oder by date you [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) first, but since [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) does not guarantee any order of results you need to `$sort` again before you group with the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operation to build the array.

Note that you are likely reducing down the "createddate" somehow as then general "distinct" items would appear to be the "user.id" and the "object_id" fields, so this does need some sort of accumulator and needs to be included for your ordering.

Then the array items will be in the order you expect.

If you need to `$limit` then you must process `$unwind` and split the limit the results. Alternately process a "limit" after the first group and following sort here.

But of course this is only practical to do for a single main grouping `_id`, being "user.id". Future mongodb releases will support `$slice`, which will make this practical for multiple grouping id's and a bit more simple in general. But it still won't be possible to "limit" the array items before that initial group over multiple primary groupind id's.

Comment: In your first grouping, you'll probably need to group the createddate with $last iso $first, since he wanted the object id's sorted by time of last visit.

Comment: Your code returns empty array, but thanks anyway. Your comments helped me to find a solution which i posted here.

Comment: @aokozlov It's a typo, as I originally typed "objectid" in the first grouping and not "object_id" as referenced later. Fixed. Also don't use `$project` as a final stage or at all unless it's really required, as it's generally just wasted cpu cycles and I/O.

Comment: @BlakesSeven yes, now it works as needed. And thanks for the last `$project` advice. But why do you always sort not only by date but also by `user.id`? We already have only one `user.id` in the set after `$match`. I think it waste of cpu too.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Also, in my solution i use `$max: '$createddate'` and it helps to avoid the first sort. (i have an index on `createddate` so it should work quick). Which way is preferred using `$max` of prior sorting and `$first`?

Comment: @aokozlov The example in point is intended to not be dependant on your initial match. If you wanted more than one value then the other stages are all the same. And no the cpu cycle difference is negligable if already containing only a single value. And "read again" that "group" is not ordered. So if you did want to `$limit` in there then you would need sorted results.